# How do I change the theme dynamically using a value stored in a provider?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to put a variable inside my `GlobalsProvider` called `themeVersion` that will have only 2 possible values. The app should change the theme based on this variable.

Below is my `main.dart`. The tricky part is that the theme is right there where the `GlobalsProvider` is also being created. What's the quickest way to refactor this so that I can drive the theme using the variable in my provider dart file?

```
import 'package:ats/providers/globals_provider.dart';
import 'package:ats/wrapper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => GlobalsProvider(),
      child: GetMaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: false,

          // Define the default brightness and colors.
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
            seedColor: Colors.red,
            // ···
            brightness: Brightness.dark,
          ),

          // Define the default `TextTheme`. Use this to specify the default
          // text styling for headlines, titles, bodies of text, and more.
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            displayLarge: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 72,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        home: const MyHomePage(title: 'My App',),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Wrapper();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution - modify this section to use a `Builder`:

```
return ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (context) => GlobalsProvider(),
  child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
    final globalsOneTimeRead = Provider.of<GlobalsProvider>(context);
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: false,

        // Define the default brightness and colors.
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
          seedColor: globalsOneTimeRead.themeColor == 1 ? Colors.green : Colors.deepPurple,
          // ···
          // brightness: Brightness.dark,
        ),

        // Define the default `TextTheme`. Use this to specify the default
        // text styling for headlines, titles, bodies of text, and more.
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          displayLarge: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 72,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'My App',),
    );
  })
);
```